# Pressing p in dash results in weird B

Tags: 12.10, unity-dash

Today I tried to open Skype in my dash and discovered that my "p" key does not work properly. Instead of p I get B. In every other application the key works properly. When I copy the text "skyBe" from dash into another application it sais "skype". I tried every other character and they seem fine, it's only the "p" key. I think that the problem is dash. Anyone else has the same problem?

Here is an image. I enter "skype" and get this:

[image]

What causes this problem and how can I fix it?

Environment:

- Lenovo W500 with German keyboard
- Ubuntu 12.10
- Language settings: English
- Keyboard layout: German

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem except with the 'g' key.  Restarting my computer fixed the problem.